# Common Lisp Applying Regex-like Patterns to Keys in PLIST

Tags: regex, lisp, common-lisp, plist

I am wondering if it is possible to apply Regex-like pattern matching to keys in a plist.

That is, suppose we have a list like this `(:input1 1 :input2 2 :input3 3 :output1 10 :output2 20 ... :expand "string here")`

The code I need to write is something along the lines of:

"If there is `:expand` and (`:input*` or `:output*`) in the list's keys, then do something and also return the `:expand` and (`:output*` or `:input*`)".

Obviously, this can be accomplished via `cond` but I do not see a clear way to write this elegantly. Hence, I thought of possibly using a Regex-like pattern on keys and basing the return on the results from that pattern search.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: This looks a lot like an XY-problem. What if you used a tree of properties: the value associated with `:input` would be another plist, etc.?

Comment: I have no control over the original structure. I am modifying this code to throw a warning when a certain scenario is encountered.

Comment: Unless you are suggesting that I walk through the original list in my sub-routine and modify it to be a tree?

Comment: The quoted part, your specification, is a little bit unclear to me: what if there are both input and output? what if the list contains other unrelated keys? Maybe you could add an example or two. You can always pre-process the list into a more appropriate data-structure, it depends a lot of your needs. For example, you could have your keys be in the form `(:input n)` instead of symbols. The problem with symbols is that you are back to unstructured land, where the only option is to parse symbol names each time you need to perform operations ("stringly typed" approach), instead of once.

Answer (score 4):

### Normalize your input

A possible first step for your algorithm that will simplify the rest of your problem is to normalize your input in a way that keep the same information in a structured way, instead of inside symbol's names. I am converting keys from symbols to either symbols or lists. You could also define your own class which represents inputs and outputs, and write generic functions that works for both.

```
(defun normalize-key (key)
  (or (cl-ppcre:register-groups-bind (symbol number)
          ("^(\\w+)(\\d+)$" (symbol-name key))
        (list (intern symbol "KEYWORD")
              (parse-integer number)))
      key))

(defun test-normalize ()
  (assert (eq (normalize-key :expand) :expand))
  (assert (equal (normalize-key :input1) '(:input 1))))
```

The above `normalize-key` deconstructs `:inputN` into a list `(:input N)`, with `N` parsed as a number. Using the above function, you can normalize the whole list (you could do that recursively too for values, if you need it):

```
(defun normalize-plist (plist)
  (loop
    for (key value) on plist by #'cddr
    collect (normalize-key key)
    collect value))

(normalize-plist
 '(:input1 1 :input2 2 :input3 3 :output1 10 :output2 20 :expand "string here"))

=> ((:INPUT 1) 1
    (:INPUT 2) 2
    (:INPUT 3) 3
    (:OUTPUT 1) 10
    (:OUTPUT 2) 20
    :EXPAND "string here")
```

From there, you should be able to implement your logic more easily.